# Is there a way to access sftp location in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sftp, spfx

I have to read the contents of a file which is in server i.e sftp location . I'm new to react typescript and wondering on how to access the sftp location from spfx webpart . Is there any library to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to connect to sftp location using javascript from a browser. You may consider using some server-side or desktop application to achieve what you want.